# Extra padding on photo and photoset posts on tumblr

Tags: html, padding, tumblr

I'm working on my first tumblr theme, and I cannot figure out what's wrong. For some reason, all of my photo and photoset posts have 3 extra pixels beneath the photo/photoset. But all of the other post types (like video posts from my html below), even though they are in the exact same class, do not have this issue.

```
{block:If2Columns}
   {block:Photo} 
      {LinkOpenTag}
          <img src="{PhotoURL-400}" />
      {LinkCloseTag}
      {block:IfShowCaption}<br />
         {block:HighRes}
            <a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">{lang:Click for high-res photo}</a>
         {/block:HighRes}
         {block:Caption}
            <p>{Caption}</p>
         {/block:Caption}
      {/block:IfShowCaption}
   {/block:Photo}
   {block:Photoset} 
      {Photoset-400}
      {block:IfShowCaption}<br />
         {block:Caption}
            <p>{Caption}</p>
         {/block:Caption}
      {/block:IfShowCaption}
   {/block:Photoset}
   {block:Video}
      {Video-400}
      {block:IfShowCaption}
         <br />{block:PlayCount}{PlayCountWithLabel}{/block:PlayCount}
         <br />{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
      {/block:IfShowCaption}
   {/block:Video}
{/block:If2Columns}
```

I tried looking at it in Firebug Lite and still couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know what the problem is/how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a test case, or some CSS please. I believe its an issue with line-height.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display:block
```

to your container.